# Cannot open pyarrow in Spyder, but can open in windows cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder, pyarrow

I am trying to read a Bigquery query and store into a data frame. I have tried both `google.cloud` and `pandas-gbq` packages require `pyarrow`.

I have installed `pyarrow`, which I can test through `pip show pyarrow`:
[image: pip show pyarrow confirms that package is installed]

I can also test through `importlib`, from which I receive the following answer:
[image: answer from importlib]

The location shown above is contained on PYTHONPATH from Spyder:
[image]

And I can also import `pyarrow` when running Python from Windows cmd.

But when I try to import it from Spyder I receive the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarrow.lib'
```

[image]

Thanks in advance for those who came this far :)

Comment: So it is finding the `pyarrow` module but it is failing to load `lib` which is a cython component and should consist of an `.so` file, a `.pyx` file and a `.pxd` file.  Regrettably that doesn't answer your question.  I don't know much about Spyder, does it run it's own version of the python interpreter?  Or is it reusing the 3.9 one that you have installed?  If it is running its own interpreter it is possible that a version mismatch is the problem.  Can you try installing `pyarrow` from within Spyder?

Comment: As far as I know, it is reusing the 3.9 I have installed, it is just an IDE. I am not sure if I can install pyarrow from Spyder. I will try to remove all `pyarrow` versions that may be installed and try again.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved:**
Apparently, Spyder was running default python interpreter version (3.7), while the pyarrow package was only installed for a more updated version, which was already installed (3.9).

I changed the interpreter on which Spyder was running and it worked:
[image]